# High degree nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to understand efficient usage patterns with neo4j, specifically in reference to high degree nodes. To give an idea of what I'm talking about, I have `User` nodes that have attributes which I have modeled as nodes. So there are relationships in my table such as

```
(:User)-[:HAS_ATTRIB]->(:AgeCategory)
```

and so on and so forth. The problem is that some of these `AgeCategory` nodes are very high degree, on the order of 100k, and queries such as

```
MATCH (u:User)-->(:AgeCategory)<--(v:User), (u)-->(:FavoriteLanguage)<--(v)
WHERE u.uid = "AAA111" AND v.uid <> u.uid
RETURN v.uid
```

(matching all users that share the same age category and favorite language as `AAA111`) are very, very slow, since you have to run over the `FavoriteLanguage` linked list once for every element in the `AgeCategory` linked list (or at least that's how I understand it).

I think it's pretty clear from the fact that this query takes minutes to resolve that I'm doing something wrong, but I am curious what the right procedure for dealing with queries like this is. Should I pull down the matching users from each query individually and compare them with an in-memory hash? Is there a way to put an index on the relationships on a node? Is this even a good idea for a schema to begin with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My intuition is it would be more efficient to first retrieve the two end points (AgeCategory and FavoriteLanguage) for the given node u, and then query the middle node v for a path with these two fixed end points.

To prove that, I created a test graph with the following components,

1. A node u:User with u.uid = 'AAA111'
2. A node c:AgeCategory
3. A node l:FavoriteLanguage
4. A relationship between u and c, u-[:HAS_AGE]->c
5. A relationship between u and l, u-[:LIKE_LANGUAGE]->l
6. 100,000 nodes v, each of which shar the same c:AgeCategory and l:FavoriteLanguage with the ndoe u, that is each v connects to l and c, v-[:HAS_AGE]->c, v-[:LIKE_LANGUAGE]->l

I run the following query 10 times, and got the average running time 10500 millis.

```
Match l:FavoriteLanguage<-[:LIKE_LANGUAGE]-u:User-[:HAS_AGE]->c:AgeCategory
Where u.uid = 'AAA111'
With l,c
Match l<-[:LIKE_LANGUAGE]-v:User-[:HAS_AGE]->c 
Where v.uid <> 'AAA111'
Return v.uid
```

With 10,000 v nodes, this query takes around 2000 millis, your query takes about 27000 millis.

With 100,000 v node, this query takes around 10500 millis, it seems to take forever with your original query.

So you might give this query a try and see if it can improve the performance with your graph.